# CouchDB _security PUT with angularJS

Tags: angularjs, http, curl, couchdb

I am using couchDB and angular for a small project. I am trying to make my database more secure and would like to know how to place, or PUT/POST, a new member to the _security document of a database without replacing the existing values. I understand the process of doing this with something like curl however do not understand how to do it using angular without overriding the existing values.

The curl would be:

```
curl -u admin -X PUT $HOST/database/_security -d '{"admins": {"names":[], "roles":[]}, "members": {"names": ["example"], "roles": []}}'
```

In angular I have this code:

```
$http({
    url: 'http://ip:5984/guestbook/_security',
    method: 'PUT',
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': auth_hash('adminAccount', 'adminPassword')
    },
    data: {
        admins: {
            names: [],
            roles: []
        },
        members: {
            names: [self.user.name],
            roles: []
        }
     }
})
```

Like I said the problem is that it is over riding what is already there, would using a different request mean it will not? the only way I can think to do this is to pull the existing _security document to the client, append and re put. surely this would create security issues as well as a large number of http requests being made.

Comment: There is no way to update parts of a security document and usually you wouldn't want to do so from a browser, but it depends on your application, of course. Maybe you can give a bit more context about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @KimStebel It is for a university project, I am not allowed to use a server such as node to achieve the overall goal, this is a small snippet. I am creating users that have access to a guestbook, this part is actually a promise after another $http where the user is created. I need to be able to add the user to the security document otherwise they will not be able to add signatures or view the guestbook.

Comment: ah, in that case it makes sense to have an admin interface where the admin can edit the list of users who have access. on the other hand, you wouldn't want users to have complete write access to the guestbook, since that would allow them to change or remove other people's entries. to achieve that, you might want to use an update handler: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PUT will overwrite the document and as you mentioned you would have to pull down the existing document before.

The security doc also has no _rev field for versioning which will lead to race conditions when multiple requests happen simultaneously. A slower request that arrives later may then overwrite the change of another request. Jan Lehnardt wrote a nice [article regarding conflicts](http://writing.jan.io/2013/12/19/understanding-couchdb-conflicts.html).

Did you take a look at the [users-db of CouchDB](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/intro/security.html#authentication-database)? It is build into CouchDB designed for the authentication of the users an application has. You can use the users-db to create users for your application without altering the configuration of admins and members (which is dangerous from a client for a guestbook).

Comment: I have not actually had a look into it, for my authentication I was seeing if the user was able to GET their _user doc as only they and admin have access. This determined if the account was real as well as the password. I will look into the method described. Thank you.